# I got length of array error in Android but array isn't null

Tags: android, arrays

I got length of array error in Android but the array isn't null.

The Codes :

```
public class xxx extends AppCompatActivity {

    TableLayout oyuntl;
    TextView oyuntv;
    String trtags, tvtags, kelimeurl, sorukelimes, cevapkelimes;
    int trtagi, tvtagi, kelimekoy, satiri, sirai, yoni, bittii, kelimei;
    ArrayList<String> kelimearray, yerarray;
    Random rastgele;
    String[] kelimebol;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_oyun);

        ArrayList<String> alfabearray = new ArrayList<String>();
        alfabearray.add("A");
        alfabearray.add("B");
        alfabearray.add("C");
        //***
        alfabearray.add("V");
        alfabearray.add("Y");
        alfabearray.add("Z");

        kelimeurl = "http://xxx.c1.biz/xxx.php";

        StringRequest kelimeal = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, kelimeurl, new Response.Listener<String> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse (String response){

                String[] kelimess = response.split("-");
                sorukelimes = kelimess[0];
                cevapkelimes = kelimess[1];

                sorukelimes = sorukelimes + " kelimenin eş anlamlısını bulmacada bulun";
                oyuntv.setText(sorukelimes);

                kelimei = cevapkelimes.length();

                rastgele = new Random();

                kelimekoy = 0;

                yerarray = new ArrayList<String>();
                kelimearray = new ArrayList<String>();

                bittii = 0;

                Runnable calistir = new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){

                while(kelimekoy == 0) {

                    satiri = rastgele.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1;
                    sirai = rastgele.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1;
                    yoni = rastgele.nextInt(5 - 1) + 1;

                    kelimebol = cevapkelimes.split("(?!^)");

                    if (yoni == 1) {

                        if (satiri >= kelimei) {

                            kelimekoy = 1;

                            for(int i = 0; i < kelimei; i++){

                                kelimearray.add(kelimebol[i]);

                                yerarray.add(String.valueOf(satiri) + "-" + String.valueOf(sirai));

                                satiri = satiri - 1;

                            }

                            bittii = 1;

                        }else{
                            kelimekoy = 0;
                        }

                    } else if (yoni == 2) {

                        if((11 - satiri) >= kelimei) {

                            kelimekoy = 1;

                            for(int ii = 0; ii < kelimei; ii++){

                                kelimearray.add(kelimebol[ii]);

                                yerarray.add(String.valueOf(satiri) + "-" + String.valueOf(sirai));

                                satiri = satiri + 1;

                            }

                            bittii = 1;

                        }else{

                            kelimekoy = 0;

                        }

                    } else if (yoni == 3) {

                        if((11 - sirai) >= kelimei){

                            kelimekoy = 1;

                            for(int iii = 0; iii < kelimei; iii++){

                                kelimearray.add(kelimebol[iii]);

                                yerarray.add(String.valueOf(satiri) + "-" + String.valueOf(sirai));

                                sirai = sirai + 1;

                            }

                            bittii = 1;

                        }else{
                            kelimekoy = 0;
                        }

                    } else if(yoni == 4){

                        if(sirai >= kelimei){

                            kelimekoy = 1;

                            for(int iiii = 0; iiii < kelimei; iiii++){

                                kelimearray.add(kelimebol[iiii]);

                                yerarray.add(String.valueOf(satiri) + "-" + String.valueOf(sirai));

                                sirai = sirai - 1;

                            }

                            bittii = 1;

                        }else{
                            kelimekoy = 0;
                        }

                    }

                }

                    }
                };

                Thread thread = new Thread(calistir);
                thread.start();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener () {
            public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError kelimeale){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), kelimeale.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            }
        });

        kelimeal.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy(70000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue kelimequeue = Volley.newRequestQueue(oyun.this);
        kelimequeue.add(kelimeal);

        TableRow.LayoutParams trp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams tvp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){

            trtagi = i;

            trtags = "tr" + String.valueOf(trtagi);

            TableRow tabler = new TableRow(oyun.this);
            tabler.setTag(trtags);
            tabler.setLayoutParams(trp);

            for(int ii = 1; ii < 11; ii++){

                tvtagi = ii;

                tvtags = String.valueOf(trtagi) + String.valueOf(tvtagi);

                TextView tabletv = new TextView(oyun.this);
                tabletv.setTag(tvtags);
                tabletv.setLayoutParams(tvp);

                Collections.shuffle(alfabearray);
                tabletv.setText(alfabearray.get(0));

                for(int yeri = 0; yeri < kelimebol.length; yeri++) {

                    String[] yerbol = yerarray.get(yeri).split("-");

                    if ((String.valueOf(trtagi) + "-" + String.valueOf(tvtagi)) == yerarray.get(yeri)) {

                        tabletv.setText(kelimearray.get(0));

                        kelimearray.remove(0);

                    } else {
                        Collections.shuffle(alfabearray);
                        tabletv.setText(alfabearray.get(0));
                    }

                }

                bittii = 2;

                tabler.addView(tabletv);

            }

            oyuntl.addView(tabler);

        }

    }
}
```

I got error in tis line :

```
for(int yeri = 0; yeri < kelimebol.length; yeri++) {
```

But I added element in "kelimebol" array in this code :

```
kelimebol = cevapkelimes.split("(?!^)");
```

How I can resolve this problem - error?

I wait your help and answers.

Note : I doesn't had a good English. I hope you can understand me. Pardon me.

Comment: It's null because you're only setting it in an asynchronous callback

Comment: @RyanM I added the code in while loop and the problem was resolved.